# Decrease the brightness of the screen on button click

Tags: android

I have a problem that I want to decrease the brightness of the screen on the button click but failed to do that. I don't know why? I have written the code of few lines but it doesn't work for me. Please suggest me the right solution regarding the same.

**Code:**

```
private void setBrightness() {  

        try {
            int curBrightnessValue = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
            layoutParams.screenBrightness = curBrightnessValue/100.0f;
            getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
        } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to good, but I think for taking effect of brightness your activity has to wait for `500ms`, Just use given below code,

```
 try {
      ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
      int brightness = Settings.System.getInt(cr,Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);            
      Settings.System.putInt(cr, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, brightness);
      WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
      lp.screenBrightness = brightness / 255.0f;
      getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.d("Bright", "toggleBrightness: " + e);
      }

      final Activity activity = this;
      Thread t = new Thread(){
        public void run()
         {
          try {
               sleep(500);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
              activity.finish();
            }
        };
        t.start();
```

**UPDATE:**

The main code is just,

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams layout = getWindow().getAttributes();
layout.screenBrightness = 1F;
getWindow().setAttributes(layout);
```

Also try this..
Try this and let me know what happen,

Comment: This code finishes Activity while calling the same code due to activity.finish() statement, when I removed this statement then this code executes but nothing affects on the screen.

Comment: For more info look at [autobright](http://code.google.com/p/autobright/source/browse/trunk/autobright/src/com/geekyouup/android/autobright/AutoBright.java)

Comment: Hey Thanx it works by increasing the divident 255.0f to 1500.0f.

Answer (score 2):

Use `IHardwareService` interface for this:

**permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.HARDWARE_TEST"></uses-permission>
```

**Modify your Code like:**

```
private void setBrightness(int brightness) {  
    try {  
      IHardwareService hardware = IHardwareService.Stub.asInterface(  
ServiceManager.getService("hardware"));  
      if (hardware != null) {  
        hardware.setScreenBacklight(brightness);  
      }  
    } catch (RemoteException doe) {            
    }
```

full example here [Changing the Screen Brightness](https://web.archive.org/web/20210224163252/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/changing-screen-brightness.html)

**OR in your case maybe possible:**

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
```

Move this to After you do `setContentView(R.layout.main);`
You can't do `getWindow().getAttributes()` before window is constructed.

Thus, your code will become

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     // MY BRIGHTNESS VARIABLES


 WindowManager.LayoutParams lp;
 float fb;
 float lb = 0;
 float hb = 1;
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
    fb = lp.screenBrightness;

   // MY CODE FROM HERE DOWN

    Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(lp.screenBrightness==fb) {
            lp.screenBrightness=lb;
            getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
        }
        if(lp.screenBrightness==lb){
            lp.screenBrightness=hb;
            getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
        }
        if(lp.screenBrightness==hb){
            lp.screenBrightness=fb;
            getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
        }

    }
} );
    //////////////////////////////////////////////




}

}
```